# Is it possible to run node in "console interpreter mode"?

Tags: javascript, node.js, console

I want to run a node shell that will work like the chrome browser console.

So it will be possible to load js files, or paste them into the console and they will run immediately and also to be able to type in new lines of code to be executed and most importantly, to not lose the state until I choose to, not until code execution ends.

Is it possible?

Comment: On windows it does that if you just type "node" ... :p

Comment: I do no know if it has all the feature you want, but did you try to run  `node` in a terminal.

Comment: I tried that, pasting in code doesn't work as expected. @rbntd

Comment: Strange, seems to work on my side. What terminal/bash/OS are you using ?

Comment: Windows 10, cmd, node 6.9.1. @rbntd

Comment: It works also for me on 'macOS'

Comment: Strange, i have the same setup. What doesn't work exactly ?

Comment: nvm, i don't think it's working either. Can't help anymore.

Comment: I found the .load <filepath> command that you can type in the interpreter to load external JS. This worked for MathJS which didn't work when I pasted. Maybe it'll help you ?

Comment: @rbntd Yes that loads the file better, but it still end the "session" (quit the node shell and return to cmd shell) after execution of the file ends thus I'm losing the state.